# How can you hard code an identity user login?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm creating a asp.net web application and using identity package for logging in. But I only want a user with an admin role to be able to register a user. My problem is that I can't register the first admin user to be able to register more users. Is it possible to hard code a default admin into the application. So there will always be 1 admin if I change database.

```
namespace IncidentReportForm.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{   
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        public static List<String> ManagerEmails = new List<String>();




public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]

            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }


            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            public List<Reports> Reports { get; set; }

            public int Manager { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        //public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(InputModel input)
        {
            string returnUrl = Url.Content("~/");
            //returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

                    //Set role
                   if (input.Manager == 0)
                   {
                        ManagerEmails.Add(Input.Email);
                        IdentityUser currentUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
                        /*var roleresult =*/
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(currentUser, "Manager");
                    }


                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);

                }
            }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just disable or bypass the admin requirement to create the first admin user (then re-enable it)

Answer (score 0):

One way to bypass the authorization is in the web.config.
This would be done in the web.config located in the Account folder (or wherever that page is located)...not the one at the root.

It would look a little like this:
Say your page is called Register.aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

[HOW TO: Control Authorization Permissions in an ASP.NET Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316871/how-to-control-authorization-permissions-in-an-asp-net-application)

Answer (score -1):

Ef or EF core has an ability named **Data Seeding**.

Seed data is data that you populate the database with at the time it is created. You use seeding to provide initial values for lookup lists, for demo purposes, proof of concepts, etc.

Data seeding is the process of populating a database with an initial set of data.

In case you are using Ef Coe there are several ways this can be accomplished in EF Core:

- Model seed data
- Manual migration customization
- Custom initialization logic

and I will give you a small sample code about **Model seed data**

As an example, this will configure seed data for a **Blog** in **OnModelCreating**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasData(new Blog {BlogId = 1, Url = "http://sample.com"});
```

To add entities that have a relationship the foreign key values need to be specified:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(
    new Post() { BlogId = 1, PostId = 1, Title = "First post", Content = "Test 1" });
```

also, you can find more detail about this useful ability on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) or in [this amazing blog](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding)

So you can seed your admin user and it'll create in the first time application run.
I suggest you read the documents to preventing produce bug and error.